# horizontal css menu <li> items repositioning under themselves if window is not in full screen

Tags: html, css, window

I have an issue with my CSS. The menu works fine but when you adjust the window from full screen to any other size, the menu cuts off at the right end and starts again on the left below the menu. I had a similar issue with a different page and I was able to fix it with position:absolute but this doesn't seem to resolve this. I'm not a beginner but I'm not a pro.  If someone could help me figure out how to make the window scroll left to right instead of moving the menu options down, that would be great.

I have a `div` tag that my css menu goes in:

```
<div id='cssmenu' align='justify' style="z-index: 1;">
```

Then I have multiple menu's that go across the top of the page

```
<ul><br>
    <li class='has-sub'>  ~a href='index.html'>Home ~/a> ~/li>  
    <li class='has-sub'>  ~a href='index.html'>General Info~/a> ~/li>  
    <li class='has-sub'>  ~a href='index.html'>Downloads~/a> ~/li>  
    <li class='has-sub'>  ~a href='index.html'> ~/a> ~/li>  
    <li class='has-sub'>  ~a href='index.html'>Home ~/a> ~/li>  
    <li class='has-sub'>  ~a href='index.html'>Home ~/a> ~/li>  
<ul>

</code>
```

Here is my CSS.

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative; 
    top: o;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu {
    height: 49px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    background: #fefefe;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fefefe),            color-stop(100%, #eee9f0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a30813;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu a {
    background: #fefefe;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fefefe), color-stop(100%, #ececec));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 49px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu > ul {
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
} 

#cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 45px; /* This value moves the menu to the left*/
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
}


#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
    content: '';
    display: relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0 !important;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #a30813;
    margin-left: -10px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    float:left;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #a30813;
    margin-left: -10px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    z-index: 1;
} 

#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background: #ececec;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ececec),    color-stop(100%, #ffeeff ef));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
    background: #ececec;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ececec), color-stop(100%, #ffeeff ef));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub {
    z-index: 1;
    padding-left: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-left: 50px;/* this value is used to align the menu*/
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

 #cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
     *margin-bottom: -1px;
     z-index: 1;
     padding-left: 0px; 
     z-index: 1;
 }

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
    background: #a30813;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d40a19;
    filter: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
    background: #72060d;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
    padding-left:55px;  /*this value moves the text to the left when highlighted*/
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
    padding-left:0; /* this keeps the sub-menu close to the drop down menu*/
} 

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
    background: #72060d;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d40a19;
    padding-left:5px; /* this aligns the txt to the left for the sub-menu */
    z-index: 1;
} 

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
    background: #5a040b;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
    padding-left:50px; /* this moves the text on the sub-menu when hovered over*/
}
```

Comment: For formatting help. please see the [Mardown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the `<li>` element is floating left-to-right.  It breaks off and starts on a new row when the width of the combined list-elements exceeds that of the `<ul>`.

What you can do is give the `<div>` a **width**:100% and **overflow**:hidden, so that you cannot see anything drop and start a new row.

Then you can give the `<ul>` a **width**:1000px, so that the `<li>` would be able to fit across the screen and be cut-off, but still somewhat visible.  [Here is what it would look like.](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/5Vr7U/1/)

The problem after that is that you would need to resize the `<li>` items, either by font or padding; best to resize with media queries if working with multiple layouts.  If you want them to resize dynamically, you can write a javascript function to handle the sizing/spacing.

Comment: Ok, when I added the "overflow:hidden" now its not displaying the sub drop down menu items. It seems like its not overlaying the submenus on top of EVERYTHING, which is what I want.  Would this be the <UL> for the sub menu issue?

Comment: Regarding the above mentioned issue, Here is an example for where I want to see the submenu, but it is not working
http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/5Vr7U/1/